# Crash in RxJava due to an observable error even though error is handled

Tags: android, crash, rx-java

I'm trying to use **RxJava (version 1.1.0)** in my android app. I've implemented a simple observable/subscriber pattern to invoke API calls over the network, like so (used 'Single' rather than a fuly-blown 'Observable' simply cause there are no multiple events to report for network calls):

```
// Observable
Single<Data> observable = Single.create(new Single.OnSubscribe<Data>() {
    @Override
    public void call(SingleSubscriber<? super Data> singleSubscriber) {
        try {
            Response<Data> response = mApi.get();

            singleSubscriber.onSuccess(response.body());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            singleSubscriber.onError(e);
        }
    }
}).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());

// Subscription
observable
    .doOnSuccess(new Action1<Data>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Data data) {
            Log.d("DBG", "success!");
        }
    })
    .doOnError(new Action1<Throwable>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Throwable throwable) {
            Log.d("DBG", "error!");
        }
    })
    .subscribe();
```

The normal flow works well - I see the 'success' log and data is received. However, when errors occur (e.g. wifi is down), the app crashes even though the error *is handled* (the 'error!' log gets reported) with the following exception (trimmed down):

```
12-16 07:33:41.572 6705-6952/com.d4vidi.app E/DBG: error!
12-16 07:33:41.572 6705-6952/com.d4vidi.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: RxComputationThreadPool-4
12-16 07:33:41.572 6705-6952/com.d4vidi.app E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.d4vidi.app, PID: 6705
12-16 07:33:41.572 6705-6952/com.d4vidi.app E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread. Add `onError` handling.
12-16 07:33:41.572 6705-6952/com.d4vidi.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:60)
12-16 07:33:41.572 6705-6952/com.d4vidi.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
12-16 07:33:41.572 6705-6952/com.d4vidi.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
12-16 07:33:41.572 6705-6952/com.d4vidi.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
12-16 07:33:41.572 6705-6952/com.d4vidi.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
12-16 07:33:41.572 6705-6952/com.d4vidi.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
12-16 07:33:41.572 6705-6952/com.d4vidi.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
12-16 07:33:41.572 6705-6952/com.d4vidi.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
12-16 07:33:41.572 6705-6952/com.d4vidi.app E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: for
12-16 07:33:41.572 6705-6952/com.d4vidi.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at rx.Single$7.onError(Single.java:1380)
12-16 07:33:41.572 6705-6952/com.d4vidi.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber._onError(SafeSubscriber.java:159)
12-16 07:33:41.572 6705-6952/com.d4vidi.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onError(SafeSubscriber.java:120)
12-16 07:33:41.572 6705-6952/com.d4vidi.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:71)
12-16 07:33:41.572 6705-6952/com.d4vidi.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:71)
12-16 07:33:41.572 6705-6952/com.d4vidi.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1$1$1.onError(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:71)
12-16 07:33:41.572 6705-6952/com.d4vidi.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at rx.Single$1$1.onError(Single.java:105)
12-16 07:33:41.572 6705-6952/com.d4vidi.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.d4vidi.app.additem.control.Controller$1.call(Controller.java:27)
12-16 07:33:41.572 6705-6952/com.d4vidi.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.d4vidi.app.additem.control.Controller$1.call(Controller.java:18)
12-16 07:33:41.572 6705-6952/com.d4vidi.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at rx.Single$1.call(Single.java:110)
12-16 07:33:41.572 6705-6952/com.d4vidi.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at rx.Single$1.call(Single.java:90)
12-16 07:33:41.572 6705-6952/com.d4vidi.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8098)
12-16 07:33:41.572 6705-6952/com.d4vidi.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1$1.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:62)
12-16 07:33:41.572 6705-6952/com.d4vidi.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
12-16 07:33:41.572 6705-6952/com.d4vidi.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422) 
12-16 07:33:41.572 6705-6952/com.d4vidi.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
12-16 07:33:41.572 6705-6952/com.d4vidi.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152) 
12-16 07:33:41.572 6705-6952/com.d4vidi.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265) 
12-16 07:33:41.572 6705-6952/com.d4vidi.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
12-16 07:33:41.572 6705-6952/com.d4vidi.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
12-16 07:33:41.572 6705-6952/com.d4vidi.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Isn't this the most fundamental usage of RxJava? Why should it crash, then, even though the error is handled in a `doOnError()` callback - am I missing something here?

Answer (score 5):

The `doOnError` doesn't handle exceptions, it allows you to peek into the exception but doesn't affect them in any other way. You still have to observe the error and use one of the `onErrorXXX` or `retry()` methods to do something about it, i.e., replace it with a valid value, retry it a few times, etc.

Comment: please have a look at my answer. I haven't just thrown an exception. Rather, I invoked onError explicitly with the caught exception as an argument. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

Fiddling around with the API I've managed to find a solution. For some reason, changing the subscriber registration as follows gets the error handler to work as expected:

```
// Subscription
observable.subscribe(
    new Action1<Data>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Data data) {
            Log.d("DBG", "success!");
        }
    },
    new Action1<Throwable>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Throwable throwable) {
            Log.d("DBG", "error!");
        }
    });
```

(i.e. I've used `subscribe(onSuccess, onError)` rather than registering callbacks and calling `subscribe()` separately).

This is very weird. I'll try to dig in further and perhaps report a bug if necessary.

Comment: The `doOnXXX` methods are side-effecting methods that don't stop the events in the streams, if you apply `doOnSuccess` twice, both will receive the values. You have to use the terminal methods such as one of the `subscribe` methods to consume events, in this case, the two-action callback version. There is no bug in RxJava but misinterpretation. I suggest you read the Grokking RxJava series of Dan Lew: http://blog.danlew.net/2014/09/15/grokking-rxjava-part-1/